# SendDelegateMessage failed to return after waiting 10 seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I've just added a very simple UIWebView based embedded browser into our app.  This loads and navigates pages fine, but as soon as I rotate the device the entire UI stops responding.  It is, however, still running and I can pause the app, and print a backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00f35bd4 in -[CALayer addAnimation:forKey:] ()
#1  0x00f283e3 in endChange ()
#2  0x00f2a535 in CALayerSetBounds ()
#3  0x00f2a2b6 in -[CALayer setBounds:] ()
#4  0x00573307 in -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] ()
#5  0x006c1a3a in -[UIWebDocumentView setFrame:] ()
#6  0x008aad59 in -[UIWebBrowserView setFrame:] ()
#7  0x006c1277 in -[UIWebDocumentView _updateSize] ()
#8  0x002a76c1 in _nsnote_callback ()
#9  0x019d4f99 in __CFXNotificationPost_old ()
#10 0x0195433a in _CFXNotificationPostNotification ()
#11 0x0029d266 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#12 0x0196d67d in __invoking___ ()
#13 0x0196d551 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#14 0x027db82a in SendDelegateMessage ()
#15 0x027ba138 in WKViewSetBoundsSize ()
#16 0x02825628 in WebCore::ScrollView::platformSetContentsSize ()
#17 0x0282552b in WebCore::ScrollView::setContentsSize ()
#18 0x027d8ccc in WebCore::FrameView::setContentsSize ()
#19 0x027e8b27 in WebCore::FrameView::adjustViewSize ()
#20 0x027c68a4 in WebCore::FrameView::layout ()
#21 0x027dd1e0 in WebCore::Document::updateLayout ()
#22 0x027dd0fe in WebCore::Document::updateLayoutIgnorePendingStylesheets ()
#23 0x0285bc7b in WebCore::CSSComputedStyleDeclaration::getPropertyCSSValue ()
#24 0x0285a768 in WebCore::CSSComputedStyleDeclaration::getPropertyCSSValue ()
#25 0x02910963 in WebCore::CSSStyleDeclaration::getPropertyCSSValue ()
#26 0x0291017b in WebCore::JSCSSStyleDeclaration::nameGetter ()
#27 0x02053d1f in JSC::JSValue::get ()
```

I sometimes, but not always, also get this in the console:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (<CFNotificationCenter 0x5e199c0 [0x1a6a3e0]>) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

And this is the WebViewController implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    backButton.enabled = NO;
    forwardButton.enabled = NO;

    pageTitle.title = [self.url absoluteString];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UI Actions

-(IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIWebViewDelegate

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    backButton.enabled = webView.canGoBack;
    forwardButton.enabled = webView.canGoForward;
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    backButton.enabled = webView.canGoBack;
    forwardButton.enabled = webView.canGoForward;
    pageTitle.title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
}
```

Could anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: This appears to only happen on in the simulator and the device works ok.  Although quite annoying, I can work around it.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question

Comment: Hey Ray! Are you loading the UIWebView in a modal view?

Comment: @rayh: if this only occurs in the simulator, it might be a good idea to [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) against the problem, potentially with a sample app if you can come up with one.

Answer (score -2):

I would check your ivars, as it would suggest to me that somethings been released and your trying to perform an operation on a nil object/pointer.